# Is it possible to use a variable as a value in a XML? (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, xml, database, variables

I want to use the values from "**valueFrom**" and "**valueTo**" as **variables** / I want to **change** them on a specific condition (JAVA). Is it possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator android:duration="4000" android:propertyName="scaleX" android:valueFrom="1" android:valueTo="14"/>

    <objectAnimator android:duration="4000" android:propertyName="scaleY" android:valueFrom="1" android:valueTo="14"/>

    <objectAnimator android:duration="2300" android:propertyName="pivotX" android:valueFrom="0" android:valueTo="2600"/>

    <objectAnimator android:duration="2300" android:propertyName="pivotY" android:valueFrom="0" android:valueTo="3900"/>

</set>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible but you would have to overwrite the XML file every time you change them.

Comment: Mhm, unfortunately it isn't so easy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299139/how-to-modify-an-objectanimator-xml-in-runtime